# Crystal Report export to pdf arabic font smaller visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015, fonts, crystal-reports

I am making a report using SAP Crystal Report version 13.0.20.2399 and Visual Studio 2015.

I can export to pdf. But the problem is the **Arabic font become little smaller and there is no space between words**

**In my web page**

[image: Web page]

**In Pdf**

[image: in pdf]

> I tried different fonts like Arial, Tahoma, Arial Universal ms.

**UPDATE**

> I tried to give long spaces between 2 words. It removed all the spaces after export to pdf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally, I found the answer. Once I change the font into **Arial Unicode MS**, then everything is ok.